# MVC updating a view's model with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using a select to list all of the site's users.  Below the select are fields that contain the selected users information.  When i select a different user i would like to refresh the view's model and populate the fields with the new selection's information.
Ultimately, i would like to use a jquery get to return the updated model and refresh the model's state to populate the fields. Is it possible to refresh a model that is already bound to a view with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really no reason to update the model. The model is server side, javascript runs on client side.

You would use an asyncronous call in javascript ([maybe jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) to a server side method to retrieve some data based on input. (Maybe a good return type would be a JSON object.) Then taking the data in that returned data to populate the existing HTML fields on your users computer. Maybe have a hidden div somewhere that is populated and appears after a users selection is made.

Keep in mind, Once your on the client side, your messing with the html, not the model. The model is server side. JavaScript is Client side.